# how do I place something in between an array

Tags: java

I have an array:

```
char[] arr = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'o'};
```

and I want to put some other object in between that array, like:

```
char[] desired = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
```

So, here I kept `l` in `arr[2] = 'l'` and added new `l` in between old `l` and `o`, but how can I do this in the code?

Comment: Have you tried anything? And at what location you want to add?

Comment: You need to copy all chars before `index` and shift / copy all chars from `index` by one. Since your array has a fixed size, you need to create a new one with `length + 1`.

Comment: You could use `StringBuffer` or `String#substring` if you are not required to to it _by hand_

Comment: @GauravJeswani thanks for helping that is what I will udr

Answer (score 2):

Arrays have a fixed length - that which is specified at declaration/assignment. Whilst there are methods that will work for your use case that involve creating a new array with additional indices for storing additional characters, I would recommend checking out the `ArrayList` class - [ArrayList docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

In short, an `ArrayList` is a resizeable array implementation of the `List` interface. One thing to note is that an `ArrayList` does not allow for the storage of primitive values, therefore in your case you would have to use the non-primitive `Character` wrapper instead of the primitive `char` type to store values. The `ArrayList.add(index, element)` method can be used to insert a specific element at a specific index within the structure - shifting other elements along the array as required to accommodate the new element.

Basic example illustrating a solution to your original question below.

```java
// New ArrayList of Character elements contatining ['h', 'e', 'l', 'o']
List<Character> al = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList('h', 'e', 'l', 'o'));
System.out.println("Original: " + al);  
al.add(2, 'l'); // At index 2, insert element 'l' 
System.out.println("Modified: " + al);
```

Output:

```
Original: [h, e, l, o]
Modified: [h, e, l, l, o]
```

Comment: Use the `List` interface on the left side instead of the `ArrayList` and leave the right generic empty (best practice).

Comment: @FaltFe Thanks for the tip on this, did some reading around it and will adopt this best practice in future - answer edited to reflect your suggestion :)